# Copy field to clipboard and keeping all formatting with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, sharepoint-online, copy-paste

I'm using SharePoint pages and script editor to build a copy button for quick copy/pasting of templates used on SharePoint. The current code I'm using works perfectly except it doesn't copy over for formatting.

For the context of this particular code, I followed these steps to build it.

1. Create a SharePoint page with a body of text.
2. Publish the page
3. Right-click on that page to inspect it using Google's Developer Console [(seen here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndmNc.png)
4. Copy the outerHTML for the div that the text field sets in
5. Pull the DIV ID from that code
6. Edit the SharePoint Page again [(seen here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTQFV.png)
7. Add DIV ID to JavaScript code into Script Editor
8. Publish page
9. Copy button works [(seen here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWsIi.png)

Using the JavaScript code below, I was hoping the copy function would copy over the formatting of the text in the SharePoint field.

**Fair warning:** I do not know anything about JavaScript. Someone was able to build this code for me, and I only know a little about how the code works outside of what I've displayed here. I don't know where to begin troubleshooting, and when I research other coding, I don't know where to begin with adding modifications to this code. I'm sorry in advance if I need some handholding.

My impression is that there is only a line or two of code, at most, that I can add to the existing code so that it keeps formatting like text size, bold, underline, hyperlinks, etc.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function myFunction(divId) {
  const copyDiv = document.getElementById(divId);

  if (copyDiv) {
    const textToCopy = copyDiv.innerText;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy)
      .then(() => {
        let tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
        tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied";
        setInterval(() => {
          tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy Template"
        }, 1000);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Could not copy text: ', err);
      });
  } else {
    console.error('Element to copy from could not be found');
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="myFunction('2ed477e2-32d7-4f46-a4a9-0a55cdba22f5')" onmouseout="outFunc()">
    <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy Template</span>
  </button>
</div>


<div class="ControlZone ControlZone--clean a_b_50a7110f" data-automation-id="CanvasControl" id="2ed477e2-32d7-4f46-a4a9-0a55cdba22f5">
  <div class="ControlZone--control">
    <div data-sp-feature-tag="Rich Text Editor" class="rte-webpart rte--ck5 rte--read-ck5 headerFontSizeLegacy" data-sp-feature-instance-id="2ed477e2-32d7-4f46-a4a9-0a55cdba22f5" dir="auto">
      <div data-automation-id="textBox" class="ck-content rteEmphasis root-161 rte-deprecated-styles">
        <div>
          <h2 id="bigger-text">Bigger Text<span class="c_b_1310c973"></span></h2>
          <a class="c_b_1310c973 e_b_1310c973 focusBorder-147" role="link" aria-label="Permalink for Bigger Text" data-sp-anchor-id="bigger-text" href="https://garmin.sharepoint.com/sites/PSSharedSupport-PSCommunityTeam/Architect-Wiki/SitePages/Test-Page.aspx#bigger-text"
            target="_self" style="left: 140px; top: 118px;"><i class="f_b_1310c973 g_b_1310c973 css-146" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <p>This is the text field from which the copy button is copied. As of now, it will not copy over formatting like <strong>bold</strong>, <i>italicized</i>, and <u>underlined</u> text formatting.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It is missing `outFunc` and an element with id=2ed477e2-32d7-4f46-a4a9-0a55cdba22f5. Please click [edit] and scroll down and click "edit above snippet" to make a [mcve]

Comment: I don't know sharepoint, but I'd try changing line 5 to `const textToCopy = copyDiv.innerHTML` instead of `innerText` to see if that preserves your formatting.  (or use `outerHTML` if you need the div tag itself included.)

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure if I did what you needed, but I tried to edit the post. I'm sorta lost on all of that so I hope that worked.

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks! I tried that, and it pasted the HTML version of the formatted text, which is insightful but, unfortunately, what I need. I feel like I'm so close to getting what I need. Any other thoughts? 

I know if I copy the text as it shows up in SharePoint and paste it into the program I'm using, it will take the formatted text. It's just a matter of getting it to copy the same way.

Comment: @mplungjan I know that the outFunc doesn't work here because the code I used references the DIV ID from SharePoint, which isn't going to work here. I'm not sure how to modify the code to work outside of that page.

Comment: Just copy the div and paste it into the snippet (click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add the div and the function

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you so much! Sorry, I'm such a noob here. I couldn't add the div in the same section but it's closer to the top. That's the entire div for the area that's being copied. I hope this helps you, help me. :P

Comment: I moved the div for you, but then realise that SO (and jsfiddle too btw) does not allow the clipboard API to run. So to test this we do actually have to copy the code to test it.

Comment: @mplungjan for some reason, that didn't work. I truly appreciate you taking the time to help me. It copies the div just fine but only copies it as plain text regardless of where I paste it. I made you a quick demo video to show you what I'm seeing because the program that I paste it into will prompt me to keep or discard the formatting when highlighting it and then copying/pasting from the SharePoint page.

Demo video:
https://imgur.com/a/Bv1gtDI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are getting the innerText of the complete div. That results in ONLY the TEXT of the `p` is copied.
2. We need to save both TEXT and HTML as blobs with the mime-types of text and html, then the recipient can choose to paste as text or as formatted text.

---

```
const myFunction = (divId) =>  {
  const copyDiv = document.getElementById(divId);

  if (copyDiv) {
    const elementToCopy = copyDiv.querySelector('p'); // otherwise we will copy the whole div
    navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({
     'text/plain': new Blob([elementToCopy.innerText], {type: 'text/plain'}),
     'text/html': new Blob([elementToCopy.innerHTML], {type: 'text/html'})
    })])
    .then(() => {
      let tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
      tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied";
      setInterval(() => {
        tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy Template"
      }, 1000);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Could not copy text: ', err);
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Element to copy from could not be found');
  }
}
```

Here is what I get in outlook

[image]

Comment: for some reason, that didn't work. I truly appreciate you taking the time to help me. It copies the div just fine but only copies it as plain text regardless of where I paste it. I made you a quick demo video to show you what I'm seeing because the program that I paste it into will prompt me to keep or discard the formatting when highlighting it and then copying/pasting from the SharePoint page.

Demo video:
https://imgur.com/a/Bv1gtDI

Comment: I get the correct formatting in outlook (see the screenshot in my answer). So perhaps your editor does not support pasting formatted stuff?

Comment: That's interesting. I don't get the format to paste into Outlook or MS Word either. Do you think it has something to do with SharePoint when you reference the editor that does not support formatting? I assume you tested this in a different environment than SharePoint.

Comment: Indeed. I just test in a browser.